# Get newest instead of oldest item from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have products table with columns 
ID, Name 
and reviews table with columns 
ID, Product_id, Text

I'm trying to get list of product names along with the newest review for every displayed product, but I'm getting the oldest review instead. I'm using the following code:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->select(array('products.*', 
        DB::raw('COUNT(reviews.product_id) as reviews_count'), 
        DB::raw('reviews.text as review_text')))
    ->where('products.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_terms.'%')
    ->join('reviews', 'reviews.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->orderBy('reviews.id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: is your id in reviews auto inc?

Comment: Yes it is, both product_id and reviews ids

Comment: try to change the order by..for example try to change it in other column just to test if it is working

Comment: Do you work with Eloquent relationship, or you for purpose use manual joins?

Comment: I'm using Eloquent relationships

Comment: Check this: http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use Eloquent for such a simple request? In your model Product create relation to Reviews. One product has many reviews. So model looks like this:

```
class Product extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Review');
    }
}
```

Than in your conntroller you could do something like this:

```
$product = Product::with('reviews')->firstOrFail();

return View::make('Viewname')->withProduct($product);
```

And than in your view:

```
@foreach ($product->reviews->sortBy('created_at') as $review) 
    {{ $review->text }} <br/>
@endforeach
```

Instead of `sortBy`, you could you `take(3)` for example, and you will get last 3 reviews etc.